# Implement arithmetic equal in Z3

Tags: c#, z3

I am implementing using Z3 c# API and I want to implement a function with which a variable of type int can be assigned an integer value. What I have thought of is:

```
public void AddEqualOperator2Constraints(Expr pOperand1, int pOperand2)
{
      Expr lOperand2 = iCtx.MkConst(pOperand2, iCtx.MkIntSort());
      BoolExpr lConstraint = iCtx.MkEq((ArithExpr)pOperand1, (ArithExpr)lOperand2);

      AddConstraintToSolver(lConstraint);
}
```

There is some thing wrong when I want to cast the second operand which is an integer into an expression. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you really want to use iCtx.MkInt(pOperand2) to create an integer constant as opposed to a logical constant.

Thus,

```
   public void AddEqualOperator2Constraints(Expr pOperand1, int pOperand2)
   {
      BoolExpr lConstraint = iCtx.MkEq((ArithExpr)pOperand1,  iCtx.MkInt(pOperand2));

      AddConstraintToSolver(lConstraint);
   }
```

Comment: Adding on to that: whatever is called "const" in Z3 is a "constant function", which is in fact the same as a "variable" in other formalisms, e.g., "f(x) = x" is a constant function and "5" is called a "numeral" in Z3.